# Could a plug-in on multiple WP sites access the same database?

Tags: database, wordpress, events, calendar, synchronize

I am building 3 WP sites and will be using The Events Calendar plug-in on each.

1. Site A will show all event listings.
2. Site B will only show the events related to the subject that site covers.
3. Site C will only show the events related to the subject that it covers.

Users will add events from each of the sites.

Is there a way for sites B&C to access Site A's database to upload events to, and display events from?

Alternately, is there a reasonable way for sites B&C to synch their event databases with Site A?

Thanks,
Andover

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to setup a [multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). The benefit is that it uses the same database for as many sites you want to setup with different prefix for (wp_,wp2_,etc...)

Once you done with that , you need to use `$wpdb`

```
global $wpdb
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

And you can get all the entries from event's table by accessing the Site A's database by prefix.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmed. I didn't realize WP multisites could do that. Will they support different TLDs?

Comment: Yes they also supprot TLDs. Link for reference : http://www.wphostinggeeks.com/install-wp-multisite-with-top-level-domains/